# spring data rest kotlin associations POST

Tags: kotlin, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, jackson-databind

I followed the tutorial http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships.
I also observed that I can create the association directly by providing the link to the relationship.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"name":"My Library"}' http://localhost:8080/libraries
curl -i -X POST -d '{"title":"Books", "library":"http://localhost:8080/libraries/1"}' -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8080/books
```

This works fine in Java and also in Kotlin when using a regular class.

However, if I use a data class in Kotlin, I get the following error

2018-04-26 14:13:43.730 ERROR 79256 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] b.e.h.RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler : org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of com.baeldung.models.Library (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/libraries/1'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of com.baeldung.models.Library (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/libraries/1') at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 1, column: 29] (through reference chain: com.baeldung.models.Book["library"])

I do have the relevant kotlin-spring, kotlin-jpa and kotlin-noarg plugins in my project.

Code is here https://github.com/vijaysl/spring-data-rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin data classes are pretty strict. It's telling you, basically, it can't construct your POKO and it's listing some of the ways it tries. One of them is with a String constructor. Others are through private field manipulation (which is the way it's been done normally).

Data classes in kotlin, if they have fields declared as `private val name:String` translate to (in java) `private final String name;` It can't assign to a `final` field (which is dirty to try to assign to a private field, but impossible when it's final; the JVM won't allow it) and there are no `getName()` or `setName()` functions which can be used as another method of hydration.

Some options:

1. Declare your variables are `var` instead of `val`. `private var name:String` is java equiavalent to `private String name` which will use field based (dirty) hydration.
2. include a specific kotlin dependency for kotlin that fixes this issue: `compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")` have a look at [this project](https://github.com/chb0github/spring-boot-kotlin-demo/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/bongiorno/sdrss/domain/resources/Employee.kt)

example kotlin class that should work for you:

```
import org.springframework.hateoas.Identifiable
import java.time.LocalDate
import javax.persistence.*
import javax.validation.constraints.*

@Entity
data class Employee(@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9]+")
                    @Size(min = 6, max = 32)
                    val name: String,
                    @Email
                    @NotNull
                    val email: String?,
                    @PastOrPresent
                    val hireDate: LocalDate = LocalDate.now(),

                    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
                    val forms:List<Form> = listOf(),
                    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
                    val reports:List<Report> = listOf(),
                    @Id @GeneratedValue( strategy =  GenerationType.IDENTITY) private val id: Long? = null): Identifiable<Long> {

    override fun getId() = id

    constructor(name:String): this(name,"$name@foo.com")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion.
1. I updated the entities to use val instead of var. That was an oversight on my part.
2. Just fixing 1 above was not sufficient. I had to remove the dependency com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin to get this to work. Not sure the reason for this. Maybe spring boot already includes the jackson library. I have updated the kotlin project example in https://github.com/vijaysl/spring-data-rest

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `@JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.DISABLED)` annotation on primary constructor. No need to disable the `com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin`.

Explanation:

- Kotlin Jackson module implies your default constructor is the JSON creator (see `KotlinValueInstantiator` class).
- Therefore, Spring Data REST does not apply its bean deserializer modifier (that is supposed to load a bean by URI) because bean properties mappings are not used for creator properties (constructor params).
- KotlinValueInstantiator tries to deserialize constructor params using standard deserializers and instantiators and this leads to the error you mentioned.

Possible solution:

Since koltin-jpa module adds a default empty constructor for JPA, you can instruct Jackson not to use the JSON creator but the default empty constructor by explicitly disabling it.

Example:

```
@Entity
class Book @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.DISABLED) constructor(

  @ManyToMany
  val libraries: ModifiableList<Library> = ArrayList(),

): AbstractPersistable<Long>(), Identifiable<Long>
```

Answer (score 0):

With kotlin all Ok.

**Just replace "data class" to "class".**

Jackson don't find empty constructor in "data class". And use other deserializator... not Uri....